# Remove UTF-8 BOM from TStream output

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, byte-order-mark, delphi-11-alexandria

I'm using Delphi 11. I have to write a UTF-8 `.csv` file without a BOM using a `TStream` object, but using `TEncoding.UTF8` produces a UTF-8 file with a BOM, so I tried using the encoding directly without success:

```
function TfMain.generateCsvFile(pathname : String ; outStr : String; create : boolean; append:boolean; close:boolean) : Boolean;
var
  //Writer: TStreamWriter;
  UTF8withoutBOM: TEncoding;
begin
  Result := False;
  UTF8withoutBOM := TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001);
  try
    if create then begin
      Writer := TStreamWriter.Create(pathname, False, UTF8WithoutBOM);
    end;
    if append then begin
      Writer.WriteLine(outStr);
      Writer.Flush;
      Result := True;
    end;
    if close then begin
      Writer.Close;
      Writer.Free;
    end;
  except
    on e : Exception do begin
      ShowMessage('Errore '+e.Message);
      lbConsole.Items.Add('Errore '+e.Message);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Is there a way to tell Delphi to remove the BOM using `TStreamWriter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a new class from `SysUtils.TUTF8Encoding` and override its virtual `GetPreamble()` method to return an empty byte array. Then use that class instead of `TEncoding.UTF8` or `TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001)`.

```
type
  TUTF8EncodingNoBOM = class(TUTF8Encoding)
  public
    function GetPreamble: TBytes; override;
  end;

function TUTF8EncodingNoBOM.GetPreamble: TBytes;
begin
  Result := nil;
end;

function TfMain.generateCsvFile(pathname : String ; outStr : String; create : boolean; append: boolean; close: boolean) : Boolean;
var
  ... 
  UTF8withoutBOM: TEncoding;
begin
  Result := False;
  UTF8withoutBOM := TUTF8EncodingNoBOM.Create;
  try
    ...
  finally    
    UTF8withoutBOM.Free;
  end;
end;
```

---

On a side note: you need to `Free()` the `TEncoding` object that is returned by `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` otherwise it will be leaked.